# How to store Users Computer Name in Database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ip

I am trying to store Visitor Computer name in my database. I have written the following code, but its only saving the ip address not computer name in database. I have used `gethostbyadd` to grab computer name.

Kindly tell me some other way to store Visitors Computer name in Database.

```
<?php

include 'connect.php';


$ip =           $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$host_name=     gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);


    $query= "insert into visitors_data (ip_address, computer_name, date, time)
             values('$ip', '$host_name', NOW(), CURTIME())";


    mysql_query($query);

?>
```

Comment: Sometimes a hostname won't be found for a particular IP address. You should be ready to handle this type of situation.

Answer (score 0):

On my quick Look up, it can be applicable to local network where it this will work fine and return the Computer Name. But when the page is accessed from a remote location, then

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

will return the Public IP address of the Network and not the Particular Client Machine. And there the

```
gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

Will give result for that Public IP address from the Network in which that Client Machine is Located. This result will be the Public hostname of that network not revealing the Name of Client Machine.

Adding to it, this will again depend on if the Reverse PTR record of that IP and Domain is Configured . If not then the Function will return the Hostname of the Hosting Provider or just the IP (normally as subdomain for that IP given be the ISP / Host)

One more exception can Hosted Dedicated Servers or VPS where a Public IP is directly pointed to a Machine. This can in most of the times reveal the hostname of the server but there can't be any users accessing a website from their server.

Hope this helps.